# is there anyway to access parent element using child element in jss

Tags: css, jss

Hi i want to access the parent element from child element in JSS, can any one help on this Please

```
<div className="parent">
this is parent
<div className="child">this is child</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Element.parentElement`.
I think this code can help you.

I can't write react code here, so I wrote it pure HTML, CSS, JS code.

```js
function myfunction() {
  var child = document.getElementsByClassName('child')[0];
  child.parentElement.style.color = "blue";
}
```

```css
.parent {
  color: red;
}
.child {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
this is parent
<div class="child">this is child</div>
</div>
<button onclick="myfunction()">click me</button>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but i want to use in JSS

Comment: What kind of action do you need?

Comment: `parentElement` works in JSX too.

Comment: parent:{ "& - .child":{ color:"blue"}}

Comment: i don't want to use any onclick , when rendering dom, it should reflect

Comment: I understand. It's an example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238976/discussion-between-sato-takeru-and-manu-panduu).

Answer (score 0):

you cannot select a parent in CSS
however you can start from the parent and use whatever Pseudo selector
for example I select the first parent element using first-child
then applied the styles I want to MuiCard-root class

```
 "&:first-child": {
  "& .MuiCard-root": {
    marginTop: 0,
  },
},
```